# How to split a column into a list and save it into a new .csv file

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a data frame with two columns: student ID and their courses. The course column has multiple values separated by ";". How can I split genres into a list and save every pair (studentID, genre1), (studetID, genre2) into a new CSV file?

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I've been trying something along the lines:
mDF.write()
    .format("csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .save("/path/to/csv");

but I'm not sure how to do it

Answer (score 1):

You could try `split` and `explode` :

```
  val df =  Seq((1,("a;b;c"))).toDF("id","values")
  df.show()

  val df2 = df.select($"id", explode(split($"values",";")).as("value"))
  df2.show()

  df2.write.option("header", "true").csv("/path/to/csv");

+---+------+
| id|values|
+---+------+
|  1| a;b;c|
+---+------+

+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|    a|
|  1|    b|
|  1|    c|
+---+-----+
```

Comment: Is the syntax for explode correct?
I am trying this but it shows error with split:
mDF.select("studentId", explode(split("courses", "|")).as("course")).write.option("header", "true").csv("/path/to/csv");

Comment: You can't use strings as column names in that select. You should import spark.implicits._ and get it by 'studentId or mDF.col("studentId") , same problem in split function, you are passing `String` instead of `Column`.